# What are the moistened wrapped towelettes called in restaurants?

Tags: word-requests

What are the moistened packaged towelettes called in restaurants? They are used to wipe the hands prior to eating. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called [お絞り](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oshibori), typically written in Kana as おしぼり.

The word お絞り comes from the verb 絞る meaning "to wring", with the honorific prefix お.

If you want to be more specific:

- 布製おしぼり are made from cloth.
- 紙製おしぼり are made from paper (these are the disposable, plastic packaged ones)

Comment: お手拭き is what I normally hear for the paper ones.